# Misaligned "edit tags" link on questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Incriminating screenshot below. Appeared when I over over the tags. Confirmed with multiple questions both on main site and on meta. Browser is Mozilla Firefox 3.6.8.

> [image: pic]

Edit: something similar also appears in the tag list at the bottom of a user's profile:

> [image: pic]

Also I've just updated to Firefox 3.6.13 and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that didn't look quite right.

Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: All better now!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this in Chrome. What browser?

Comment: Bug encountered with Firefox 3.6.8 and Firefox 3.6.13.

Comment: Funnily enough, the fact that it looks correct in chrome is a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310047/css-why-is-vertical-align-baseline-stop-working-on-firefox-when-using-overflow

Comment: I hope you're not using Chrome *Beta* Jeff ;)